# Debug info in Dwarf file missing?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

*Issue*: I'm building a framework (SQLite.swift) written in *Swift* using Xcode 7.3.1 and trying to check on the debug info using `dwarfdump`, but I get the following output:

```
File: SQLite.swift-master/Output/SQLite_GR-Debug-iphoneuniversal/SQLite.framework/SQLite (arm64)
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
.debug_info contents:
< EMPTY >
```

*Why*: I need to check the debug information to find out why the framework won't run on another user's session, which I suspect might come for hard-coded paths at build time.

My target is setup to (afaict) allow debug symbols. Is there a specific option to set to make sure that the dwarfdump information is present?

[image: Target build options relative to debug info]